# Ctrl+N keyboard shortcut on IntelliJ/Android Studio

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I very often use `Ctrl+N` keyboard shortcut when working in Android Studio/IntelliJ, to open a given class by its prefix. Many times the popup window gets defocused when I type class name prefix and I start typing in the code area instead (and I am sure that this is a problem inside IntelliJ, as I am not touching my touchpad, etc.).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Never ever happened to me and I use IntelliJ on my laptop extensively.

Comment: I know, it's strange. Can I lookup my current bindings for a given shortcut?

Comment: Meo's suggestion seems fairly close to what you're seeing actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue: [Go to Class window loses focus during typing](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112015), there might be a workaround which would work for you.